# How much close should two spaces be in the Gromov-Hausdorff distance to be homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, metric-geometry

Here I am considering the [Gromov-Hausdorff convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov%E2%80%93Hausdorff_convergence) for metric spaces. I know two compact metric spaces are isometric if and only if $d_{GH}(X,Y)=0$, where $d_{GH}$ denotes the Gromov-Hausdorff (pseudo)distance. I was wondering if a weaker assumption (e.g. $d_{GH}(X,Y)$ small enough) could imply homeomorphism between $X$ and $Y$.

To be more concrete, I am especially interested in the following problem: let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $d_n$ a sequence of metrics on $X$ such that $(X,d_n)$ converges to $(X,d)$ in the Gromov-Hausdorff convergence. Can I say that the topology induced by $d_n$ is equivalent to the native topology (induced by $d$) of $X$, at least for $n$ large enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the sequence of annuli $A=\{1\le |z|\le 1+1/n\}$ in the complex plane. Their limit in the GH-sense is the unit circle. Since the annuli and the circle have the same cardinality, you can assume (although it is very unnatural, GH-convergence is set up to avoid this) that the corresponding metrics are defined on the same set. If you want Riemannian manifolds as your examples, think of a sequence of tori converging to the unit circle. On the positive side, [Perelman's stability theorem](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703002) (used in the proof of his more famous theorem) states that under certain conditions ("Alexandrov", "curvature bounds", "noncollapsing"), if $X_n$'s GH-converge to $X$ then for large $n$ indeed $X$ is homeomorphic to $X_n$.